# Creating a function of DT table in shiny

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function for DT table where just specifying the columns name in the parameter, the column should get hidden

```
dt_table <- function(data, 
                     colhidden = c(a)){
  datatable(data, 
            options = list(
              columnDefs = list(
                list(visible=FALSE, targets=colhidden)
              )
            ))
}
 dt_table(iris,colhidden = c('Species'))
```

But unfortunately, the column is not getting hidden. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`targets` needs the column number which you can get with `match`. Try -

```
library(DT)
dt_table <- function(data, colhidden) {
datatable(data, 
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(visible=FALSE, targets=match(colhidden, colnames(data))))
            )
          )
}

dt_table(iris,colhidden = c('Species'))
dt_table(iris,colhidden = c('Species', 'Sepal.Length'))
```

Comment: Thanks but if I add ````rownames = F```` to my function, the rownames are not getting hidden. Why?

Comment: That is not relevant to the question asked but if I use `datatable(data, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=match(colhidden, colnames(data))))), rownames = FALSE)` it hides the rownames for me.